# Length of the shortest phrase with given keywords in a large text

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This question was asked to one of my friends in an interview.

Given two keywords, we have to find the length of the shortest phrase with the given keywords in a large text.
The keywords may appear in any order in that text.
Constraint : Keep an efficient data structure so that each time the text need not be parsed for queries with different keywords

> eg. keywords: "one", "four" text: "one two three four five four six
>   one"
>
> here the shortest such phrase is "four six one" rather than "one two
>   three four"

The solution we have in mind is:
Built a BST with all the words of the text. Each node maintains the locations of the words.
(This will be a sorted list) When a query comes search [O(logn)] both words, Find the minimum difference between their locations in [O(n)] Thus making it effectively [O (nlogn)].

Can we do better ?

Comment: How are you getting O(n log n) from an O(log n) op and an O(n) op? That's O(n). But the second op isn't actually O(n), it's O(# of word matches), which may be less than O(n) depending on the data distribution.

Comment: Yes :) I was wrong! It is O(n) Regd. Second op. both searches results in an sorted array of locations, Finding minimum distance between a pair from them. Yes it is O(# of times the keywords occur in text)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a hash table for the reverse index, i.e. a hash table from words (keywords) to sorted lists of their locations in the text. When you get the two keywords of the query, looking up their incidence records is then O(1) operation.

Finding the minimum difference between the locations of incidence is O(k) operation where k is the length of the longer incidence list. In anomalous cases it could be that k is near to n, but in realistic use not (unless you use "the" and "a" as the two keywords, but those types of words, known as stop words, are normally excluded from full text search anyway).

In usual setting, k is very small compared to n so this should be very fast, i.e. O(1) + O(number of occurrences of the more common keyword).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this can be solved using [Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Without loss of generality i can re-phrase the question as:

> Given search space `S = {s1, s2, ..., sn}`, a needle pair `(si, sj)`, we have to find position pair `(k, l)` such that:
>
> 1. `(sk, sl) == (si, sj)`
> 2. `distance(k, l)` is minimum.

A recursive solution for the problem can be formulated by:

> `Cost(m) =`
>
> 1. `LARGEST_NUMBER, if m = 0`
> 2. `Min (Cost(m-1), distance(S[m], Latest_si)), if m > 0 and S[m] == sj`
> 3. `Min (Cost(m-1), distance(S[m], Latest_sj)), if m > 0 and S[m] == si`
> 4. `Cost(m-1), if m > 0 and S[m] != (si, sj)`

Where,

1. `Cost(m)` is the optimization function. It represents minimum distance between `(si, sj)` in search space `S[1:m]`.
2. `Latest_si` is the latest position of `si`.
3. `Latest_sj` is the latest position of `sj`.

This can be converted into an `O(n)` bottoms up loop with space complexity of `O(n)` to store `Cost`.

Here is an implementation of above algorithm in Python:

```
def min_phrase (S, si, sj):
  Cost = []
  for i in S:
    Cost.append([len(S), [-1, -1]])

  latest_si = -1
  latest_sj = -1

  for idx, v in enumerate(S):
    if v == si:
      if latest_sj >=0:
        cost = idx - latest_sj
        if cost < Cost[idx - 1][0]:
          Cost[idx] = [cost, [latest_sj, idx]]
        else:
          Cost[idx] = Cost[idx - 1]
      else:
        Cost[idx] = Cost[idx - 1]

      latest_si = idx

    elif v == sj:
      if latest_si >=0:
        cost = idx - latest_si
        if cost < Cost[idx - 1][0]:
          Cost[idx] = [cost, [latest_si, idx]]
        else:
          Cost[idx] = Cost[idx - 1]
      else:
        Cost[idx] = Cost[idx - 1]

      latest_sj = idx

    else:
      Cost[idx] = Cost[idx - 1]

  return Cost[len(S) - 1]


if __name__ == '__main__':
  S = ("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "four", "six", "one")
  si = "one"
  sj = "four"

  result = min_phrase(S, si, sj)
  if result[1][0] == -1 or result[1][1] == -1:
    print "No solution found"
  else:
    print "Cost: {0}".format(result[0])
    print "Phrase: {0}".format(" ".join(S[result[1][0] : result[1][1] + 1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

First split up the text in phrases. Assign a number to each of these phrases. Now each word in the text is present in some of these phrases. Put the phrase lengths in an array. Put the words in a hash table, with the numbers of the phrases in which they are present as an ordered array.

Now when we want the shortest phrase containing two words, first get the two prase-arrays for the words, then do a set intersection, then look up the phrase lengths for the resulting phrase numbers. Pick the shortest.

Comment: You are only allowed to parse the text once. So how do you know what a phrase is?

Comment: Since the problem states that you must find the shortest phrase containing both words, you can assume there are rules for splitting the text up in these phrases.

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing the point, but this looks like it can be done using  a simple `String[] text` array in O(n) instead of some fancy data structure.

- 1* load the text into the array.
- 2* find the location of keyword `x` and track its position.
- 3* find the location of keyword `y` and track its position.
- 4* mark the distance between x and y.
- 5* the first time around set `minx = x` and `miny = y`
- 6* keep finding x and y, alternating, changing the value of minx and miny each time a new smaller distance is found.
- 7* finally return the substring bounded by minx and miny